# Check one data lies within range of two date field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this data:

[image]

And, I am trying to compare that one of the date is within range of the given data, but without any success. Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_emp_leave_details
WHERE emp_id          =  81
AND leave_start_date  >= '2019-09-03'
AND leave_end_date    <= '2019-09-03'
```

The type of both column is set to date.

Update:

```
 $bindings   = array(
            ":leave_start_date" => $switchDate,
            ":leave_end_date"   => $switchDate,
            ":empId"            => $row["EmployeeNamePK"]
        );


        $sqlValidation =
            "SELECT * FROM tbl_emp_leave_details
             WHERE emp_id          =  :empId
             AND :leave_start_date >= leave_start_date
             AND :leave_end_date   <= leave_end_date";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without success"? What should be returned?

Comment: 'within range of the given data' - does this mean the given data can be 2 dates as opposed to one in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are using wrong logic here. As per your requirement, your input date value should fall [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) the `leave_start_date` and `leave_end_date`. So , switch your logic to other way around:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_emp_leave_details
WHERE emp_id          =  81 
  AND '2019-09-03' BETWEEN leave_start_date AND leave_end_date
```

---

One can also write this query using [`>=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_greater-than-or-equal) and [`<=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_less-than-or-equal) operators. Conceptually, the input date value should be greater than or equal to the `leave_start_date`. Also, for it to fall within the define range, it should be less than or equal to the `leave_end_date`:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_emp_leave_details
WHERE emp_id          =  81
AND '2019-09-03'  >= leave_start_date
AND '2019-09-03'  <= leave_end_date
```

Comment: How do i write last query with binding syntax.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan add the PHP code (or any other language) to your question, so that I can edit it accordingly and give answer.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan updated PHP code is fine. It should be working as expected. Are you facing any issues ?